# Adding a string in front of a parameter for a form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to add a string in front of a paramemter on my form so that when the user submits something on the form, it posts to an external API and my client can log in to freshdesk.com, and instead of saying `BOB`, it will say `Hello from BOB`.

```
Hello from [:username]
```

I tried this in my view:

```
= f.text_field "Hello From, #{:username}"
```

but it does not work. I also tried to use a value:

```
= f.text_field :subject, value: "Hello From, #{:username}"
```

but that does not work either. Here is my form:

```
= form_for(:contacts, url: contacts_path) do |f|
  = f.error_messages
  = f.label :subject, "Name"
  %span{style: 'color: red'} *
  = f.text_field :subject, class: "text_field width_100_percent"
  %br
  %br    
  = f.label "Email"
  %span{style: 'color: red'} *
  %br    
  = f.email_field :email, class: "text_field width_100_percent"
  %br
  %br
  = f.label "Question(s), and/or feedback"
  %span{style: 'color: red'} *
  %br
  = f.text_area :description, class: "text_field width_100_percent", style: 'height: 100px;'
  %br
  %br
  = f.submit "Submit", class: 'btn btn-warning'
```

Here is my controller:

```
def new
  @contacts = Form.new
end

def create
  @contacts = Form.new(params[:contacts])
  @contacts.post_tickets(params[:contacts])
  if @contacts.valid?
    flash[:success] = "Message sent! Thank you for conacting us."
    redirect_to new_contact_path
  else
    flash[:alert] = "Please fill in the required fields"
    render action: 'new'
  end
end
```

this is from my model

```
class Form
  include ActiveModel::Validations
  include ActiveModel::Conversion
  include ActiveModel::Translation
  extend  ActiveModel::Naming

  attr_accessor :config, :client, :subject, :email, :custom_field_phone_number_28445, 
            :custom_field_name_28445, :custom_field_company_28445, :description, 
            :custom_field

  validates_presence_of :subject, :message => '^Please enter your name'
  validates_presence_of :description, :message => '^Question(s), and/or feedback can not be blank'
  validates :email, presence: true  
  validates_format_of :email, :with => /^[-a-z0-9_+\.]+\@([-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z0-9]{2,4}$/i

  def initialize(attributes = {})
    attributes.each do |name, value|
      @attributes = attributes
    end

    self.config = YAML.load_file("#{Rails.root}/config/fresh_desk.yml")[Rails.env]
  self.client = Freshdesk.new(config[:url], config[:api_key], config[:password])
    end

    def read_attribute_for_validation(key)
      @attributes[key]
    end

    def post_tickets(params)
      client.post_tickets(params)
    end

    def persisted?
      false
    end
   end
```

Comment: Have you tried changing the form to `form_for(@contacts)` and interpolation to `"Hello From, #{f.object.username}"`

Comment: @rubish - yeah i've tried that did not work....when i change it to @contacts i get a undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass

Comment: Try changing `@contacts` variable name to `@contact`. Rails is highly conventional.

Comment: @rubish - when i get rid of the s at the end of contacts i get a undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class

Comment: Can you post your model. You either stick with rails conventions(here naming conventions) for easy life or stray away from conventions and face issues which you need to resolve. Its your choice, but I would suggest sticking to conventions.

Comment: @rubish - added my model please see edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your view should have straightforward fields with no magic. We'll use the Form class to do the complicated stuff.

```
= f.text_field :subject
```

The method call to post_tickets does not need to receive the `params` because the Form object has already been initialized with the `params` values. Also, you shouldn't post the ticket, I think, unless the object is valid, right?

```
def create
  @contacts = Form.new(params[:contacts])
  if @contacts.valid?
    @contacts.post_tickets
    flash[:success] = "Message sent! Thank you for contacting us."
    redirect_to new_contact_path
  else
    flash[:alert] = "Please fill in the required fields"
    render action: 'new'
  end
end
```

Your Form model should be responsible for modifying the :subject parameter to include the prefix:

```
class Form
  # Some code omitted

  def initialize(attributes = {})
    attributes.each do |name, value|
      send("#{name}=", value)
    end
  end

  def post_tickets
    client.post_tickets({
      :whatever_fields => whatever_attribute, 
      :username => username, 
      :subject => "Hello from, #{subject}", 
      :email => email, 
      :description => description
    })
  end

end
```

That way, the Form object has the correct values as submitted by the user, but you've overwritten the posted subject so that it will return the combined string you want, with "Hello from..."

In post_tickets, reference directly the parameters you want to send, via the attributes with which the Form object has been initialized. In the case of `subject`, you'll send a combined value instead.

Please note, I've rewritten your initialize to use a more classic attribute setting method.

Thoughts, questions?

Comment: thank you for the detailed answer....However I am getting an undefined method `read_attribute'

Comment: is it because im not using active record?

Comment: I've updated my answer to remove the overwritten read accessor and just, instead, sent a modified string in the values passed to `client.post_tickets`.

Comment: Do you still have the `self.config` and `self.client` set correctly? Are the attributes on the Form class object getting set correctly? What are you using to debug? Are you familiar with ruby debugger?

Comment: Im sorry so i got the form to post now.....but when it posts all it says is "Hello from, " and does not get the name that was inputted...thank you for your help by the way

Comment: But the other attributes are sent correctly? Try, in post_tickets, setting a local variable `full_subject = "Hello from, " + subject` and then in the `client.post_tickets` arguments, give it `:subject => full_subject`. Does that work?

Comment: well the api really only cares about the email field being valid and going through so what i did was changed it to :email => "ricky@yahoo.com" just to get it to post to see if the message would get appended

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37201/discussion-between-carlos-drew-and-ricky-ahn)

Answer (score 1):

You should do this in your model by adding your substring before the value que form will send you. This seems business logic, it shouldn't be in the view.

```
def post_tickets(params)
   client.username = "Hello From, " + client.username
   client.post_tickets(params)
end
```

Comment: its actually not an email...its a form that submits to another websites API...its called FRESHDESK.com

Comment: Then I suppose you have an action some controller that receives this form, haven't you? You can get the param from the form and append the substring before calling those web services.

Comment: i posted my controller

Comment: I think i'd create a new method "welcome" in the model and call it from controller when you are going to call the API. This method only have to return "Hello From, #{username}".

Comment: dam isnt there a simple solution for this...i can't find any other discussions about this either..